# Focus disables mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have some text-areas in a web page and I have used the below code snippet to focus on textarea which was required as textarea was not allowing to enter text in itself. But using below code not allowing user to click and add text any where in between already entered text. User is only able to go through the arrow keys but not using the mouse. Do we have any hack to fix it?

```
 $('textarea').on('click',
        function () {
            $(this).focus();
        });
```

Comment: click will automatically set the focus on the element. What is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Could you only call focus if the textarea is empty?

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.